# Active Record Reputation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using the gem Active Record Reputation System in my application for the voting system. In this gem, the add_evaluation method has 3 parameters.

```
@blog.add_evaluation(:likes, value, source_object)
```

What is the source object supposed to be?

Comment: Probably the `current_user`. Try reading the documentation for the gem. If that doesn't help read the source code.

Comment: What if we want anyone who clicks on the link to be able to vote and not the signed in user? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Blog model you define the has_evaluation and there you define who is giving that evaluation. That is the source object (most typically a user)